# How to remove specific lines from a text file, using Python

Tags: python

I have a text file with data in it. I am trying to create a python code that will format this data in a particular way so another code I have can read it as an input. So, I am trying to remove specific lines and columns, etc. The text file contains some information at the top of the file, and then columns and columns of numerical data below it. **However, I only want the numerical data. I do not want the first 34 lines** of other information written in the text file.

So, my current question is: **How can I remove specific lines of a text file? And how do I print this result so I can see if it worked or not?**

Before you come at me: Yes, I have looked up my question on StackOverflow. I still don't get it, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I need your help! :)

[(Image of my text file for reference)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kn4cN.png)

Since each of the lines I want to remove in the text file begin with a '#', maybe it would be possible to tell the code to remove all lines that begin with "#'. Or maybe I should just specify I want the first 34 lines deleted. Either way, I'm confused on how to do this.

**Separated below are all my different attempts:** (Don't worry, I have imported pandas for my attempts, it's just not written here.)

```
with open('EBSD_data.txt','r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines() 
with open('EBSD_data.txt','w') as f:
     for lines in lines:
    if line.strip("\n").startswith('#'):
      f.write(lines)
```

---

```
with open('EBSD_data.txt', 'r') as E:
    data = E.read().splitlines(True)
with open('EBSD_data.txt', 'w') as EB:
    EB.writelines(data[34:])
    print(EB.read)
```

---

```
with open('EBSD_data.txt', 'w') as data: 
  for lines in data:
    if not lines.startswith('#'):
      data.write(lines)
with open('EBSD_data.txt', 'r') as data2:
     print(data2)
```

---

```
x = open('EBSD_data.txt')
for line in x:
  if line.startswith('#'):
    del(line)
x.head()
```

---

```
lines = []
with open(r'EBSD_data.txt','r') as fp:
  lines = fp.readlines()
with open(r'EBSD_data.txt','w') as data:
 for number, line in enumerate(lines):
  if number not in [34]:
    fp.write(line)
```

---

With some of these attempts, it'll look like it runs fine, but then I have issues with printing my results. **The typical error I am encountering** after trying to print my result is:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='EBSD_data.txt' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

Any guidance you could give would be great! **Thank you! :)**

Comment: which example and line is throwing the error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As you have tagged this question with `pandas`, I can't help but suggest using the `read_csv` pandas function: `df = pd.read_csv(skiprows=34, header=None)` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: @CaptainCaveman, my first attempt for example gives me that error.

Comment: Share the text file as text - not as an image

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler, I just edited my post and removed the 'pandas' tag so maybe you are able to help now?

Answer (score 1):

I personally would always write to a new file and keep the original one...\

This should work:

```
with open('EBSD_data.txt', 'r') as data: 
  with open('EBSD_data_filtered.txt', 'w') as outfile:
      for line in data:
          if not line.startswith('#'):
              outfile.write(line)

with open('EBSD_data_filtered.txt', 'r') as data2:
    for line in data2:
        print(line)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! This way worked well! :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually reading each line with a Python context manager, you can use [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), skipping the first 34 rows of the file (`skiprows=34`), and without reading any column names from the file (`header=None`):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('EBSD_data.txt', skiprows=34, header=None)

# print first five rows to confirm expected result
print(df.head())

# Optional: write result back to a CSV file, without the default 
# pandas integer index
df.to_csv('EBSD_data_filtered.txt', index=None)
```